# getting errors running at cmd line

Tags: django

exec(open("./path/to/script.py").read(), globals()) works for me in the python interactive console shell

howver i get no output and my script has 3 print functions that i am looking for to output the reason i am in intwracve shellmode..is i tried many times to run my script at command line or IDLE only to get django settings issue or main package not a package or even the no mudule errors

only here on this thread am i getting some progress

does any one know how to get output at the console..??

Comment: hello ..i am posting my question with a bug or problem i am having in django cuz im wondering if its a virtualenv issue that might solve it.......so like i have a project in django that i use for llooking up entries in my documents/articles library and for the most part it works..except if i go to add or modify the .txt files that make up the docs folder i have which is right next to the templates folder......to be continued

Comment: so what happens is the additons or modifications i make to these .txt files in theis docs folder , dont update when i make a look up query...and so i am trying many different things to solve this and one of things was to run at the windows cmd line, my file filterword.py that filters the terms/words in each document and ..here is the issue...i get many errros...like .models module not found..or django settings not confirgured or even _main_ is not a package......to be contiuned

Comment: so one partial progress i found on the net was to at the cmd line do ...python manage.py shell.....this takes you to the <interactive console> shell python interpreter...so appartnylt this will set all needed django settings...and then there i can do ....import index(my parent app folder) from index.models import Document ( the class) ..from index.models import TermFrequency ..from index.models import DocFreuqnecy ......all these commnnds NEVER work at the cmd line it self...to be contiuned

Comment: .i would get the above mentioned errors..so then once i do that..i dont actually know how to run the python filterwords.py at the interactive console...so finally i found this........exec(open("./path/to/script.py").read(), globals())... or even just ....exec(open("./path/to/script.py").read())...so this command is supposed to run and excute the script...and it works ..i guess cuz i get the blinking cursor..but i get no output......if i go to the windows cmd line....it fails again saying module not foundf or the other errors i said.........to be contd

Comment: so then i tried making a modification to a .txt file in the docs folder..but still no output at the interactive console........so would u know what im missing out here to actually have my project update the.txt filles and also why i get no output at the Interactive console shell but erros at the cmd prompt???..is it a virtual env base issue??......thxz for the consideration ....plz read this comment and the prevoius 4 4 as one comment since there are limits here.....thxz alot for any help

Comment: im leaning towards just trying out a test folder and put all the code in one file and run it..this should not cause conflicts?/..if i cant get past the import no module and related errors..thxz again